# how can I make this calculator using only one method?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to make this calculator
I can make it using 4 methods, one for addition one for subtraction and ..... but I want to make it a simple as possible.
how can I perform the 4 main actions using one method and then call it in static main?

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    final static String first = "first number: ";
    final static String sec = "second number: ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what do you want to use? (multiply (input *), divide (input /), subtract (input -), addition (input +)");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        double answer = calculation(input);                 ----------------------
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
    public static double calculation(double element){       ----------------------
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(first);
        double firstInput = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(sec);
        double secInput = scanner.nextDouble();
        return firstInput element secInput;                 ----------------------
    }
}
```

can I change the `element` to (`+ - * /`) ?
(the ------------------ part is were I have a problem)

Comment: Are you sure the `element` should be of type `double`?

Comment: I know it shouldn't be, but I don't know what to put instead of it

Comment: element should be an enum type.

Comment: ok I'll give it a try

Comment: nope enum didn't work(or maybe I dont know how to use it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perform it using `enum` and `lambda` functions. This approach allows you to add operations to your code easily, without need of rewriting your calculation method.
First of all use `Scanner` with `try-with-resources` or call `scanner.close()` after `Scanner` is no longer needed. Then probably better not to create two `Scanner` object
, instead just unite your input parts in one method (If you still want to use two `Scanner` instances remember to wrap `System.in` in decorator to prevent it from closing).  Also you could probably add some validation to prevent input errors(and let user try to input data again). The main idea is to create enum which contains a `BiFunction` for every operation, that you apply to your pair of numbers. It could look like this:

```java
public class Main {

    private final static String first = "first number: ";
    private final static String sec = "second number: ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String operationTypes = Arrays.stream(OperationType.values())
                    .map(type -> String.format("%s (input %s)", type.toString(), type.sign))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("(", ", ", ")"));
            System.out.println("what do you want to use? " + operationTypes);
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println(first);
            double firstInput = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(sec);
            double secInput = scanner.nextDouble();
            OperationType operationType = OperationType.fromSign(input).orElseThrow();
            double answer = calculation(operationType, firstInput, secInput);
            System.out.println(answer);
        }
    }

    public static double calculation(OperationType operationType, double firstInput, double secInput) {
        return operationType.operation.apply(firstInput, secInput);
    }

    enum OperationType {

        ADD("+", Double::sum),
        SUBTRACT("-", (a, b) -> a - b),
        MULTIPLY("*", (a, b) -> a * b),
        DIVIDE("/", (a, b) -> a / b);

        String sign;
        BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> operation;

        OperationType(String sign, BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> operation) {
            this.sign = sign;
            this.operation = operation;
        }

        public static Optional<OperationType> fromSign(String sign) {
            return Arrays.stream(OperationType.values())
                    .filter(operationType -> operationType.sign.equals(sign))
                    .findAny();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name().toLowerCase();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thaaaanks man It worked. got to learn enum I guess lol

Answer (score 1):

You might wanna take a look at OOP principles, using inheritance and polymorphism, you should be able to have a single method defined in a interface and multiple implementations of it in your classes, so you can have a Calculation interface with a execute method an then you implement that interface with a class like Sum where the execute method does the real sum.

```
public interface Calculation {
    Double execute(Double a, Double b);
}

public class Sum implements Calculation {
    @Override
    public Double execute(Double a, Double b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("what do you want to use? (multiply => *, divide => /, subtract => -, addition => +");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        Calculation calculation;
        if (input.equals("+")) calculation = new Sum();
        else calculation = new Sum();// Just initializing calculation to avoid compilation error
        double answer = execute(calculation);
    }

    private static double execute(Calculation calculation){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double firstInput = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(firstInput);
        double secInput = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(secInput);
        return calculation.execute(firstInput, secInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you give me like a source code or something so I can understand better? :(

Comment: I just edited my original answer, this helps you?

Comment: Nice, do you understand the principle behind the code? These OOP principles are very important to a good application designed, it might not be a necessity for you right now, but if you need further explanation I would be glad to help.

Comment: yes thank you I didn't understand it and was scrolling through youtube xD, an explanation would be really helpful

Comment: So, the first thing I think you should be aware of is how to use polymorphism, this is a tricky concept until you start putting it into practice. It basically means that when you have a parent class or an interface you can override its methods in your own class and do different logic in different classes that implements or extends those parents. This basically explains why you can declare `Calculation` and then override its method in `Sum`.

Comment: Then SOLID enters in the game, the Dependency inversion principle says, "One should depend upon abstractions, [not] concretions.", so instead of declaring variables as `Sum`, you should use its abstraction, `Calculation`. By doing that, you can attribute any implementation of `Calculation` in the code and use it in the same way you would use calculation, as foreseen in the Liskov substitution principle, "Objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.".

Comment: Applying this principle, you are able to add other calculations into your code by adding new classes implementing `Calculations`. You can add a new class `Subtraction` which overrides `execute` with `return a - b` and then add a new `if` statement on the main method, so when the user inputs a "-", you attribute a `Substraction` object to `calculation`.

Comment: Something a didn't mention before is Strategy, a designer pattern used in those cases where you have those if statements you would use to instantiate the `Calculation`. It basically will give you the ability to do the same thing I did in the sample code on a bigger scale.

Comment: You can also take a look in those links that explains this concepts a little better. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/object-oriented-programming-concepts-21bb035f7260/                                                               
https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles                                                                                                                             https://www.baeldung.com/solid-principles